# Winphone8.1 development: Can I get a List of al files stored within the Assets folder?

Tags: file, windows-phone-8.1, assets

I am running win8.1 , and VS2013 SP3, trying to create a windows phone app which should retrieve all the document names and paths (for later reference) from the 'Assets' folder. 
I added a bunch of word documents in the Assets folder and set the build to content, and copy to always.

Is it possible to get a list of all files (or file names) in the assets folder?
I can't seem to find the way to do it.

What I can do is reference a specific file, but what I would like to do, is list out all the file names/paths within the Assets folder and show the details of these files in a specific view...

I tried the following:

```C#
var package = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

var assetsFolder = await package.GetFolderAsync("Assets");

foreach (var file in await assetsFolder.GetFilesAsync())
{
    _documents.Add(new Document() { Category = section, Title = file.Name, Uri = file.Path });
}
```

This code freezes on the foreach line...?

I would very much appreciate some guidance or references in this matter.

Comment: Write `await assetsFolder.GetFilesAsync()` outside `foreach`.

Comment: Do you have a WP8.1 device to test this on?  The lines of code works pretty well on my device.

Comment: @Xyroid: I tried that and it would still freeze. Using the WP emulator by the way.....

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware Yes, I can hook up my WP8.1_device, but I did the testing using the WP emulator... 
You think the emulator could be the problem?

Comment: Yes, I ran the above code on my phone, I was able to get all the default .png files from the asset folder.  Would you like a screenshot of breakpoints for proof?

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware Yes sure, thanks! Later today I'll try running the code on the 'physical' device. See, if it works.

Comment: I will add the complete code that I as a solution, maybe it will help you find out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's the way you're calling it.

Here's mine with screenshots.

I only call it once the whole page has loaded.

```C#
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ReadAssetFolder();
}

public async void ReadAssetFolder()
{
    var package = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    var assetsFolder = await package.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
    foreach (var file in await assetsFolder.GetFilesAsync())
    {
        int debug_var = 1;
    }

}
```

---

Screenshot of when the debugger hits my breakpoint:

[image]

---

Screenshot of my Asset folder

[image]

---

Finally all my files have these Properties

[image]

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Thank! Definitely a call issue. This works fine, calling it from NavigatedTo(s,e), in order to use some filter parameter. And runs fine in the emulator.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct; unfortunately I don't seem to be having enough reputation points for upvoting your answer.

Comment: NP, it's just for my sake.  I tend to only look at questions without the solved check mark :),  Cheers.